# Recursively adding rows to a dataframe

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, recursion, dataframe

I am new to spark. I have some `json` data that comes as an `HttpResponse`. I'll need to store this data in hive tables. Every `HttpGet` request returns a json which will be a single row in the table. Due to this, I am having to write single rows as files in the hive table directory.

But I feel having too many small files will reduce the speed and efficiency. So is there a way I can recursively add new rows to the `Dataframe` and write it to the hive table directory all at once. I feel this will also reduce the runtime of my spark code.

Example:

```
for(i <- 1 to 10){
 newDF = hiveContext.read.json("path")
 df = df.union(newDF)
}
df.write()
```

I understand that the dataframes are immutable. Is there a way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mostly on the right track, what you want to do is to obtain multiple single records as a `Seq[DataFrame]`, and then reduce the `Seq[DataFrame]` to a single `DataFrame` by unioning them.

Going from the code you provided:

```
val BatchSize = 100
val HiveTableName = "table"

(0 until BatchSize).
map(_ => hiveContext.read.json("path")).
reduce(_ union _).
write.insertInto(HiveTableName)
```

Alternatively, if you want to perform the HTTP requests as you go, we can do that too. Let's assume you have a function that does the HTTP request and converts it into a DataFrame:

```
def obtainRecord(...): DataFrame = ???
```

You can do something along the lines of:

```
val HiveTableName = "table"
val OtherHiveTableName = "other_table"
val jsonArray = ???

val batched: DataFrame =
    jsonArray.
    map { parameter =>
      obtainRecord(parameter)
    }.
    reduce(_ union _)
batched.write.insertInto(HiveTableName)
batched.select($"...").write.insertInto(OtherHiveTableName)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am trying to implement this. For posting my get request, I'll need a parameter from each element of a json array(which is fetched earlier). So, is there a better way to implement the for loop so that I can have a variable which increases with each iteration(this variable is used to access the parameter in each element of the array)?

Comment: Do you just need an index that increments from 0 to whatever?

Comment: I've just updated the answer to I think better reflect what you are trying to do. This assumes you would like to process the fetched JSON array in one go (and write to a single file). You can also split the JSON array first, or alternatively concatenate multiple JSON arrays, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: It's strange, but I don't see the option of `.map` for the `jsonArray` in my IDE. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the type of `jsonArray`?  You mentioned that it's a "json array", so I figured it's an array of some sort.

Comment: It works now, I did `arr.toArray.map`. Will try the solution now. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect jsonArray isn't an array. What JSON library are you using? It should be trivial to convert it to an `Array` (or some other `Seq`).

Comment: I am using `json simple 1.1.1`. The `jsonArray` was being returned by another java class. Not sure what type scala took it as. 
Now, Is there a way I can split the `Dataframe` returned by the `obtainRecord` into two and union the two dataframes for each iteration separately? Because, in my use case, I need to write a single column of the `dataframe` to a different table. is there a way to achieve this? Writing another function for this purpose and getting the jsonArr again does not seem an effective solution.

Comment: Once you have reduced your data into a single `DataFrame`, you can split it up and process it however you want (including writing to multiple tables).

Comment: Java classes and Scala classes are identical things, Scala doesn't "take" Java classes as a different type, unless it is explicitly or implicitly converted. Here's the javadoc for JSONArray, which should show you how to convert it to an Array - http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/index.html?org/json/simple/JSONArray.html. You can also use scala.collection.JavaConverters._ to perform the conversion if you prefer.

Comment: How do I split the final `dataframe` on one column?

Comment: Here's the Scala Doc for DataFrame, which should help you through whatever transformation you were hoping to accomplish - http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

Comment: Thanks for everything! it works now. Although the only problem is, I have other datasets to be fetched from the API. Iterating over the array for every dataset(3 iterations in total for 3 datasets) is surely going to be costly than iterating over the array once and collecting a single record of all the records with each iteration.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly misusing Spark. Apache Spark is analytical system, not a database API. There is no benefit of using Spark to modify Hive database like this. It will only bring a severe performance penalty without benefiting from any of the Spark features, including distributed processing.

Instead you should use Hive client directly to perform transactional operations.

Comment: I am sorry, but did you understand my question? I am looking to save the dataframe that I got from a Json to the hive table directory. I am not trying to modify Hive tables/databases using spark.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question; it should be a comment on the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you can batch-download all of the data (for example with a script using curl or some other program) and store it in a file first (or many files, spark can load an entire directory at once) you can then load that file(or files) all at once into spark to do your processing.  I would also check to see it the webapi as any endpoints to fetch all the data you need instead of just one record at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What you've give is a good approach. But there is no way I can fetch all the data at a time from the API. And I'll need to save the dataframe as a json file. Is it possible to create a json file with all the records(using java) ? If yes, I can just read that file into my dataframe.

Comment: @HemanthAnnavarapu yes that is what I was suggesting, just download all the data into a file or several files ahead of time.  Something like `curl -w "\n" [url] >> [jsonfile]` in a loop over all urls should work.  You could also do the download with java or scala or any other language you like.